Google App Script: Switches the row values from one tab to another tab based on the value passed in a specific column
I'm looking for the Google App Script to move row values from one tab to anther tab.
What I Wanted:
I wanted to move the row values from Tab:1 to Tab:2 when "M Status" is Married. Again I wanted to move row values from Tab:2 to Tab:1 when I change the "M Status" value to Single.
My Project
Google Sheet Tab:1
Google Sheet Tab:2
App Script
function onEdit(e){
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let val = range.getValue();
  let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if (col == 4 && val != '' && val == 'Married'){
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let ssourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Singles');
    let mtargetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Married');
    let sdata = ssourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,ssourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    sdata[0][0] = '';
    mtargetSheet.appendRow(sdata[0]); 
    ssourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }

  else if (col == 4 && val != '' && val == 'Single'){
    let ms = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let msourceSheet = ms.getSheetByName('Married');
    let stargetSheet = ms.getSheetByName('Singles');
    let mdata = msourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,msourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    mdata[0][0] = '';
    stargetSheet.appendRow(mdata[0]); 
    msourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}

Issue What I'm facing with this script
The row values got moved to respective tab. But the next row(Pair of rows) also getting moved to the next tab even though the value for M Status is different.
Example:
I have changed the value for M Status of row 1201 to 'Married' in Tab:1. After that the value for 1201 & 1202 rows got moved to Tab:2 even though value is 'Single'.
Tab:1(Singles)



S No
Name
Age
M Status




1200
Bird
24
Single


1201
Petrol
22
Single


1202
TVP
23
Single


1203
Daddy
46
Single



Actual:
Tab:2(Married)



S No
Name
Age
M Status




1201
Petrol
22
Married


1202
TVP
23
Single



Expected:
Tab:1(Singles)



S No
Name
Age
M Status




1200
Bird
24
Single


1202
TVP
23
Single


1203
Daddy
46
Single



Tab:2(Married)



S No
Name
Age
M Status




1201
Petrol
22
Married




It sounds like you have an installable trigger set up to run onEdit(). Remove that trigger. The onEdit(e) function is a simple trigger that runs automatically without any setup. You are currently running the function twice every time the user edits the spreadsheet.

Hi @doubleunary
Thanks for the above comment.  It fix the issue and working as expected.
